# How to create an intermediate table using liquibase?

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, jpa, liquibase

I have two entities, and I want to create a table that relate them.

I want to model this relation: a project has many workers and one worker is only in one project. I am using JPA and Spring-boot.

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Worker worker;

// Getters & setters...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Worker{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

// Getters & setters...
}
```

With this, I have two tables, one called "Project" and other called "Worker". Now I want to create an intermediate table having as columns the ID of the project and the ID of the worker in this project, to know what workers are working in what project, and once I have this I could re-assigned the project for a particular worker. For example I want to have the following tables:

Relation table (different workers can work in the same project):

---

|ID | ID_PROJECT | ID_WORKER|

---

|1  |      1     |     1    |

---

|2  |      1     |     2    |

---

|3  |      2     |     3    |

Worker:

---

|ID | ID_WORKER|

---

|1  |     1    |

---

|2  |     2    |

---

|3  |     3    |

Project:

---

|ID | ID_PROJECT|

---

|1  |     1    |

---

|2  |     2    |

---

|3  |     3    |

I'm using H2 database. Also I'm dealing with liquibase.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need the ID column on the relation table because you can use both foreign keys as the primary key.
2. Now you have a one-to-many relationship between these two entities.

   ```
   @Entity 
   public class Project {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private long id;

       @OneToMany
       private List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();

       // Getters & setters...
   }
   ```

Then it depends how you name the relation table.
If you name it project_worker then you don't have to do anything.

Otherwise you may need the @JoinTable annotatoin:

```
@JoinTable(
    name="<name-of-the-relation-table",
    joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="WORKER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
)
```

Comment: Why do you use a OneToMany annotation instead of the ManyToOne I had?

Comment: Because a project can have many workers with the intermediate table. Otherwise you don't need the intermediate table.

Comment: And if I want to create this table with liquibase with a YAML file, how can I specify the foreign keys and all this things?

Comment: Simply read the documentation. There are plenty of examples: https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_foreign_key_constraint.html